# tiling WM with resizable stack windows?

Tags: linux, window-manager, dwm

Right now I'm using dwm and for the most part loving it. It does almost everything I want, which is great, but there is one more thing I'd like that I'm not sure what WM can or can't do, or if there's a patch for dwm to make it possible. I'll regularly watch a video while chatting, and I usually have a terminal open next to it. See screenshot for an example. What I'd like is to be able to make the video wider, which would make the terminal narrower.

[image: not working image D:]

For anyone who can't see the image, a quick ascii depiction of what I have vs what I want:

```
+-----------------+
|                 |
|     MASTER      |
+--------+--------+
|        |        |
| STACK1 | STACK2 |
|        |        |
+--------+--------+

+-----------------+
|                 |
|     MASTER      |
+-----------+-----+
|           |     |
|  STACK1   | STK2|
|           |     |
+-----------+-----+
```

EDIT: Herbstluftwm is very configurable, and I've got exactly what I want now. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use awesome wm and all I could tell is that's possible on awesome (bound to meta-something, all key bindings are described in the awesome manpage). I don't know dwm but as in awesome, you should be able to define a specific layout if you often use it).

If you can't find how to do this on the standard dwm documentation, give a try to awesome since it's… awesome :-)

Comment: Was looking into awesome for a while. Awesome, musca, and wmii all seem to be able to do this. I know awesome at least is based on dwm, so I'll give that a shot first.

Comment: Not finding anything to do it in awesome, giving musca a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Not finding anything to do this with either dwm or awesome, but I have been able to get it to work in euclid-wm (i have a few problems with this, but may stick with it), musca (which uses what are odd hotkeys to me and uses dmenu to switch tabs and do commands, which is odd but nice), wmii (which I'll be installing shortly, and am looking forward to, being made by the same people who made dwm), and ratpoison (which I don't have much desire to try, but should be able to do it, being a manual tiler). thinking, xmonad should able to do it too.

I guess my ideal WM would be euclid-like tiling with dwm everything else. :/ Not good enough to build my own WM, though. Maybe there's something to get it to work on awesome.